# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib'” when I add python3 support with buildroot

Tags: python-3.x, zlib, buildroot

When I build the linux image with buildroot, I have enable the python3 and python zlib in the config like below:

```
BR2_PACKAGE_OPENCV3=y
BR2_PACKAGE_OPENCV3_LIB_PYTHON=y
BR2_PACKAGE_OPENCV3_LIB_IMGCODECS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_OPENCV3_LIB_IMGPROC=y
BR2_PACKAGE_OPENCV3_WITH_JPEG=y
BR2_PACKAGE_PYTHON3_ZLIB=y
```

Build is ok, and I can enter into python3, but the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib' always happened when I import some package.

anyone know how to rolve it.

thanks.

Comment: This is something that gets tested in CI, and it currently succeeds: https://gitlab.com/buildroot.org/buildroot/-/jobs/269139411 - https://git.buildroot.org/buildroot/tree/support/testing/tests/package/test_python.py#n39

Comment: Have you just tried to perform `make clean; make`?